# I don't understand gcc '-Wl,-(' ...'-Wl,-)'

Tags: gcc

During a cross compile step the following command is being issued:

```
gnu-gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -r -o librtld.map.o '-Wl,-(' allobjs.os libc_pic.a -lgcc '-Wl,-)' -Wl,-Map,librtld.mapT
```

I cannot find any description what the '-Wl,-('  ... '-Wl,-)' means???

Comment: From where do you have these options? Where were they used? What gcc version may that be?

Comment: gcc 4.x ; generate glibc/elf

Comment: See [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-groups-of-archives) for the docu for `-(` and `-)`, and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-Wl) for the docu of `-Wl`.

Answer (score 0):

-Wl, is what is being passed to the linker `ld` and it accepts the syntax `-( archives -)`.

> The specified archives are searched repeatedly until no new undefined references are created.

Comment: file "allobjs.os" is a bin-file (ELF), not an archive.

Comment: Yeah, and there is an option too.  My guess is that the linker is being gracious.